# Is it possible to set Hyper as the default terminal?

Tags: command-line, 20.04

I tried to run

```
sudo update-alternatives --config x-terminal-emulator
```

but it doesn't show up in the list, just the default gnome one, this is in Ubuntu 20.04.

Comment: Do you have a "Preferred Applications" menu entry?

Comment: the terminal isn't an option from that menu, using gnome 3.36.2

Answer (score 4):

you need to install hyper as `update-alternatives` first.. then you can select it from your command in the question..

I tried to install it and see..
I installed it with a deb package..

and ran `which hyper`

```
pratap@i7-6550U:~$ which hyper
/usr/local/bin/hyper
pratap@i7-6550U:~$
```

Create a script with below content and run it with root priviliges

```
#!/bin/bash

update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/x-terminal-emulator x-terminal-emulator /usr/local/bin/hyper 0
update-alternatives --set x-terminal-emulator /usr/local/bin/hyper
```

Example:

```
pratap@i7-6550U:~$ sudo update-alternatives --config x-terminal-emulator 
[sudo] password for pratap: 
There are 2 choices for the alternative x-terminal-emulator (providing /usr/bin/x-terminal-emulator).

  Selection    Path                             Priority   Status
------------------------------------------------------------
  0            /usr/bin/gnome-terminal.wrapper   40        auto mode
  1            /usr/bin/gnome-terminal.wrapper   40        manual mode
* 2            /usr/local/bin/hyper              0         manual mode

Press <enter> to keep the current choice[*], or type selection number:
```

---

After reading the comments,

By tweaking the `desktop-icons` extension you can somewhat achieve this.

[image]

Comment: Thanks! That got me halfway there, CTRL + ALT + T will open a new terminal with hyper now, but if I right-click and select open in terminal it'll still uses the default gnome term. And for some reason, if I try to open a terminal from the right-click menu on the desktop now nothing happens.

Comment: the one on the desktop is configured by Ubuntu's out of the box extension `desktop-icons`.. and the other one i think nautilus controls..

Comment: I tried to tweak the said extension `desktop-icons` and this is the result.. If you can set the `--working-directory` with hyper.. it is possible to open hyper with desktop as directory.. https://i.stack.imgur.com/oAwFV.gif

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/x-terminal-emulator x-terminal-emulator /opt/Hyper/hyper 50
```

See https://github.com/vercel/hyper/issues/2764#issuecomment-374437229

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu!  This answer doesn't appear to be substantially different from the existing (and better explained) answer.